# How to disable cursor blinking on lubuntu i3?

Tags: i3, eclipse, cursor, tiling-wm

The Eclipse IDE uses the OS's settings regarding cursor/caret blinking.
That's why I want to know how to disable this using i3wm (on a lubuntu 18.04 install).
When I login using LXDE, the cursor is not blinking as I disabled this in the lxsession configs.
Does anyone know how to do this in i3?

Answer (score 0):

On http://www.jurta.org/en/prog/noblink I found an answer that disables cursor blinking for all GTK3-based applications:

In the file ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini add the following line:

```
gtk-cursor-blink = 0
```